# Are these the same term? Intuition tells me they are the same, but can we derive them one from other?

Tags: boolean-algebra

D+GI vs D+D'GI, are they the sam term ?  I even draw a true table for it.
But how can we do it with boolean algebra? Adding a truth table.

Where D+GI is the POS from the table and D+D'GI is the SOP from the table.
I believe they should be the same.

[image]

Comment: No they are not sam. If you have a true table then please add it into your question.

Comment: Have a look at this PDF: http://www.gti.bh/Library/assets/part2-s9luuiwx.pdf. They have a proof that `A+A'B=A+B`, but I consider the truth table to be a better proof on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D + GI

D + (D + D') GI

D + DGI + D'GI

D (1 + GI) + D'GI

D (1) + D'GI

D + D'GI

Comment: Wait: shoud D+1+D'GI not always be 1 (if + is the OR operator)

Comment: What's the point of the `D (1 + GI) + D'GI` step, if `DGI` simplifies to `1`? You might as well remove it

Comment: @JvO Oops. Fixed it